# How to change picture based into a selected option?

Tags: html, image, web

I would like to change the user picture as he change a select option.

```
<form name="main" method="post">
    <div class="lock-box text-center">
        <div class="lock-name">$:mainform.render()</div>
        <img src="static/ux/images/lock_thumb.jpg" alt="lock avatar"/>
        <div class="lock-pwd">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="exampleInputPassword2" class="form-control lock-input" />
                <button class="btn btn-lock" type="submit">
                  <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is what my `$:mainform.render()` generates:

```
<select id="mpfUser" name="">
  <option value="John">John</option>
  <option value="Mary">Mary</option>
</select>
```

I'm showing below how it would be like:

User selecting his name and his picture is shown:
[image]

Another user selecting his name and the picture change it too:
[image]

Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

General idea is:

```
$('#mpfUser').on('change', function() {
    var SelectedImage = $('#mpfUser').val();
    $('#image_id').attr("src", SelectedImage );
});
```

You need to add "id" attribute to your "image" tag so you can easily find it. Then make sure that values of "select" element are pointing to images (names and values are different things - user see names, script getting values), it should be something like this:

```
<select id="mpfUser" name="">
  <option value="path/to/images/John.jpg">John</option>
  <option value="path/to/images/Mary.jpg">Mary</option>
</select>
```